# What is the technical term for this style lighting?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, recessed-lighting

It’s basically looking like LED strip lights, whose light bounces off the ceiling, and the strips are on top of some sort of mold/ceiling fascia. I don’t even know what to google to find a picture to add to the post

Comment: indirect lighting

Comment: actually making one for my son at the moment... led strip and wood cut to hold the led so it is recessed... Can't buy that in a shop...

Comment: I used to call it "cove lighting" but not sure if that's the right name.  Back in the day, you'd use common fluorescent tubes with a ballast with a very low ballast factor.  But today LED strips make it crazy easy.

Comment: Uplighting also comes to mind now... but that is just a particular form of indirect...

Comment: I couldn't find anything except Indirect Lighting on the Illuminating Engineering Society list of definitions [ANSI/IES RP-16-17].  Really, the EIS actually exists.

Comment: I’ve always heard either ‘uplighting’ or ‘cove lighting’. I like the LED pucks and tubed strips like, ehem, that Scandinavian store sells. Unitized, stringable, and easy to clean compared to the cheaper, raw led strips. They do cost more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indirect lighting.
[example here](https://www.deltalight.com/en/light-topics/indirect-lighting)

Usually the light source is hidden by an archtectural feature, so the feature is constructed by normal building means and then the light source is hidden in it.

At my house we have one strip light hidden in an open topped curtain pelmet and another hidden behind an one of the exposed rafters.

These are 5' flourescent tubes with 40 year old iron ballasts.

Led strips could be hidden in a cornice moulding. etc.

it's going to be tricky to clean.

Comment: If it is sensibly designed then it can easily be removed for cleaning...